# jQuery: restore to defaults after scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a footer which is sticked to the bottom of the page. When the user scrolls down the footer margin-bottom is changed to 20px and the color changes from black to white. Here for I used the following jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.scrollTop() >= 10) {
                $("footer").animate({
                    marginBottom: "30px",
                    backgroundColor: "fff"
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
});
```

When the user scrolls back to the top the footer should return to the bottom of the screen and the color should turn from white to black again. I tried to use an else-statement, but without any luck.

**Found it:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( window ).scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.scrollTop() <= 5) {
   $("footer").stop().animate({marginBottom: "0px", color: "fff", backgroundColor: "000"}, 1000);
   } else if ($this.scrollTop() >= 5) {
   $("footer").stop().animate({marginBottom: "30px", color: "000", backgroundColor: "fff"}, 1000);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: can you give the original link to check ?

Comment: liquigit.nl/test_jquery

Comment: Ok, Fine. So the problem is solved now, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
.footerback{
      margin-bottom:0;
      background-color:#000000;
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.scrollTop() >= 10) {
            $("footer").animate({
                marginBottom: "30px",
                backgroundColor: "fff"
            }, 2000);
        }
       else{
        $("footer").addClass("footerback");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it didn't do the trick.. The first try seems to work on a iPad/iPhone but not on Firefox or Safari on the Mac

Comment: I have checked in firefox now and here it is working.